# perl print ldap tree hierarchy at command line

Tags: ldap, perl

Is there a way to print a tree like view of an existing ldap directory at the command line with perl? Like the 'tree' command does with files/directories, but for ldap?

Answer (score 3):

Not out of the box, but using `Net::LDAP` and a little bit of your own `printf` magic, you too can have a tree-like LDAP representation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already aware of net::ldap and have my own perl scripts to do some searches and filters. What I'm looking for is how to order the entries correctly